# Transitions between JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

First of all... I'd like to say that I am not interested in using the card layout for this... Unless it's necessary (which means that not using the card layout would be result in unnecessary workarounds and complex code). This is for learning purposes after all and I will look into the card layout very soon enough anyway...

Okay so my question is pretty basic GUI layout I guess. My code is not working and this whole layouting confuses me quite a lot...

I'm having trouble how to make the transition between JPanels like this:

I have one window. I press a button, the old window is replaced by another window. I press a button and that window will be replaced by another window.

I'd like to add that I am skipping a lot of irrelevant code in my example below...

I start off with a JFrame:

```
  public class StartWindow extends JFrame{
   public StartWindow(){
     //Add JButton & ActionListener
     //When the button is pressed:
          add(new NextWindow()); 
   }
   public static void main(String [] args){
    new StartWindow(); 
   }
}
```

then I have several JPanels...

```
public class NextWindow extends JPanel{
  public NextWindow(){
    //Add a JButton & ActionListener
    //When the button is pressed:
       add(new NextWindow2()); 
       remove(this); 
      //This does not work. Nothing happens. 

}
}

public class NextWindow2 extends JPanel{ // Stuff and so on}
```

So, I'd like to know a proper way to handle this situation!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a panel to itself.  You need to remove the panel from the JFrame, add the new one to it, and call revalidate() on the JFrame.

Comment: Yeah but I don't have access to the JFrame in the NextWindow. :/

Comment: @optional Well you can fix that.  You have to rethink your approach since what you are doing right not won't work.  You'll want a JPanel inside the JFrame that has a button and a JPanel.  I'd suggest BorderLayout for your main panel.  When the button is pushed remove from the center of the border layout and add a new one to it.